# Why is my JavaScript too slow for this Scramblies task?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the following task:

> Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.

The code I have written goes through the initial tests but fails on the final attempt with the following error: "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)".
What is wrong here?

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
   
let array1 = str1.split("").sort(); 
let array2 = str2.split("").sort();
let count = 0;
 
for(let a = 0; a <= array1.length && count < array2.length; a++) {
    if(array2[count] === array1[a]){
      count++;  
      }
  }
  
return (count === array2.length);
}
```

Comment: Can you add examples of string pairs for which the function would return true/false?

Comment: What's the final test that's failing?

Comment: By the way, there's a little "mistake" in your function (probably it doesn't even change the return value): `a` should never become `array1.length`, it should be `a < array1.length` instead of `a <= array1.length`.

Comment: @LucaKiebel, the examples are
<pre>scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt', 'codewars') ==> True
scramble('katas', 'steak') ==> False <code>

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it is just too slow to pass the last test.

The slowest part of your code is sorting. You can easily do without sorting, by creating an object that under one-character keys has quantity of that character (so for example "Hello world" becomes `{"H": 1, "e": 1, "l": 3, "w": 1, "o": 2, "r": 1, "d": 1}`. You can do that in O(n) with this "one-liner" function:

```
function getCharFrequencies(str) {
    return str.split("").reduce(
        function(container, char) {
            (container[char] += 1) || (container[char] = 1);
            return container;
        }, 
    {});
}
```

Then, you can just pass each string into that function and compare all character frequencies from `str2` with frequencies from `str1` to see whether you can make `str2` out of `str1`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Would you mind explaining this part of your code to me? 
`(container[char] += 1) || (container[char] = 1);`

Comment: That is a common trick which is basically a shortcut for `if (container[char] === undefined) container[char] = 1; else container[char] += 1`

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading your explanation above your code. What do you mean by "by creating an object that under one-character keys has quantity of that character"? I am just not following the grammar

Answer (score -1):

`if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2` doesn't this mean `str2` has to include all of the `str1`'s characters? Your function probably isn't failing it just requires so much time to operate on the final test.

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
    for (const letter of str2) {
        if (!str1.includes(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No, that would return `true` for `str1 = 'of'` and `str2 = 'oo'` but should return `false` because neither `of` nor `fo` is equal to `oo` (only permutations of length 2 are relevant here).

Comment: Furthermore, I think the op doesn't search for better implementations but for the actual reason of the test failing (better implementation might be `return (array2.join('')).includes(array1.join(''))` after defining `array1`, `array2` like in the question).

Comment: I don't even think its really timing out; for input string lengths m and n sorting will probably take O(n*log(n) + m*log(m)) and the loop will run in O(n). This will take quite long strings to time out (with 12s run time). Of couse there are more efficient algorithms like counting the characters for each input string (yielding maps `c1` and `c2`) and then comparing whether for each entry in `c2` the corresponding count in `c1` is greater or equal.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that both strings should have the same size, and just if that's the case, otherwise some chars will be left over, this should work:

```
const scramble = (str1, str2) => {
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) return false;

    const _str1 = str1.split('').sort().join('');
    const _str2 = str2.split('').sort().join('');

    if(_str1 === _str2) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually strings not necessarily should be of the same size
`Test.assertEquals(scramble('scriptingjava','javascript'),true);
  Test.assertEquals(scramble('scriptsjava','javascripts'),true);
  Test.assertEquals(scramble('jscripts','javascript'),false);
  Test.assertEquals(scramble('aabbcamaomsccdd','commas'),true);`

Comment: Ok, then as already suggested the right way to do it, even for performance purposes, is to create a map of char => count, being that str1 should have at least the same or a higher number per each one than str2.